# Why I cant see all List elements when I try to reach them?

Tags: c#, controller

When I debug my code I can see lots of elements inside the List variable. But When I would like to call these elements for the IF control I can't see some elements and I can see some of them. Even though I tried to look everywhere I couldn't see reason. You can see what I actually tried to do. Can anyone has any idea?

List features = await se.SearchByIdAsync(gdbVersionName, metadata, featureTypeName, featureId, true);

I can reach 'Dimension' but visual studio warns me about 'Parts'.

[image]

[image: second image]

Error message is; 'Geometry' does not contain a definition for 'Parts' and no accessible extension method 'Parts' accepting a first argument of type 'Geometry' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I suspect the *compile-time* type here is `Geometry`, but the *execution-time* type is a subtype... and that the subtype has the `Parts` property, but `Geometry` doesn't. That's only a suspicion though - with a [mcve], we'd be able to say for sure...

Comment: You probably need to cast to the type containing `Parts`. The watch-windows does this implicitely for you when you dive into the object-structre

Comment: Looks like Geometry is a Polyline. It is not an array or list.

Comment: Yes its Polyline but why it affects Parts not Dimension. Still doesnt look logical to me 